# Apache - The requested URL /erp was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-14.04

I am using apache as my web server running on ubuntu 14.04 and I have some web apps inside /var/www/html. Problem is, the default index.html page, which is in the same directory, gets displayed OK if I hit the server. However, when I try to access the applications in the same directory, I get the error - The requested URL /erp/ was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

Try run:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to set correct permissions on the directories of your web apps?

like so

```
chmod 755 erp -R
```

Comment: And please add information about your LAMP installation. Do you use XAMPP, or did you just do `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`? that  would be helpful

Comment: Questions about the question should be posted as comments. Answers should not contain questions.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on the question